# Java compiler error not making any sense (<identifier> expected)

Tags: java, casting

I have done a lot of searching for what this compiler error `<identifier> expected` means, and none of them seem to apply to my situation.  Really sorry if this is a duplicate or basic info, but I can't find anything anywhere.

The following code works fine.  Note that I am positive `myObject1` is indeed a `HashSet<String>` so the cast is ok.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashSet<String> s1 = (HashSet<String>) myObject1;
```

The following code does NOT work fine.  It will compile, but with warnings.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashSet<String> s1;
s1 = (HashSet<String>) myObject1;
```

So then I try the code below.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashSet<String> s1;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
s1 = (HashSet<String>) myObject1;
```

Now it refuses to even compile, giving me the `<identifier> expected` error that is puzzling me so much.  The `^` symbol in my command line is pointing right before the `=` in the last line.  I'm not sure what on earth I could be expected to put BETWEEN the `s1` and the `=`.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Since the compiler expects a declaration there, the `s1` is parsed as a type name, then of course it expects an entity of type `s1` to be named next.

Comment: Outside the scope of the question, you should use `Set<String>` instead of `HashSet<String>`. Even if you know the implementation class on developing stage, you should think on interfaces. What if somebody later decides to move the code to `TreeSet`, the team *must* change all these files having `HashSet` and move it to `TreeSet`?

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, I know you just told me this same thing in a different question and I was still making the same mistake here... thanks for the reminder. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't apply an annotation to a simple assignment statement. From [section 9.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7):

> Annotations may be used as modifiers in any declaration, whether package (§7.4.1), class (§8.1.1) (including enums (§8.9)), interface (§9.1.1) (including annotation types (§9.6)), field (§8.3.1, §9.3), method (§8.4.3, §9.4), formal parameter (§8.4.1), constructor (§8.8.3), or local variable (§14.4.1).

I agree that the compiler error message could be rather clearer, admittedly...

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I've edited my OP slightly to reflect what I'm really trying to do.  If I want to declare `s1` on one line but assign it later... is there any way to suppress the warning that I get at assignment?  Other than putting an annotation for the entire method, of course, which seems sloppy.

Comment: use a temporary variable and assign the temporary variable later to s1, while the temporary variable has the correct type

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the Java Api for Annotations.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#LOCAL_VARIABLE

There you can see, that SupressWarnings has the target LOCAL_VARIABLE.

And LOCAL_VARIABLE stands for the declaration not the assignment.